# QTestlib unit testing project to access the classes in the main project within QTCreator

Tags: qt-creator, qtestlib

I am using QT Creator and want to run my unit tests in a separate project. How do I reference the classes in the main project from my test project?

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old question, but here are a few steps to make this easy:

- Move most of your config from `main_project.pro` file to a `main_project.pri` file.
- Use relative paths, relative to you *.pri or *.pro files, using `$$PWD/path/to/file` syntax where `$$PWD` is your *.pri or *.pro file location.
- Include `*.pri` file using `include($$PWD/main_project.pri)`
- Create a `test` project in your `main_project` folder.
- In `test/test.pro`, add the line `include($$PWD/../main_project.pri)` to import the relevant configuration from you main_project.

I can add more details if there is some interest.

Once the basic setup is working, it's quite handy as you can create a separate project for each module you want to test plus global test_suite that run all the other tests. If you find that many test projects share some configuration, you can create a separate `common.pri` file in `test/common` to include in all your test projects.

Once, that's in place, it quite easy to generate a small script to automatically create a test project when in order to test a new module, resulting quite an efficient testing workflow...